# ¿Cómo eliminar registros duplicados en una tabla sin PK?

Tags: sql

Estoy tratando de eliminar uno de los registros duplicados en una tabla sin PK con esta consulta, obviamente SQL no sabe cual de los dos eliminar y no se como combinarlos, requiero de su ayuda por favor.

```
DELETE FROM Ventas
WHERE fecha_venta IN (
SELECT fecha_venta
FROM Ventas
GROUP BY fecha_venta
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Valores duplicados:

```
fecha_venta | monto_venta | F | M
---------------------------------
2017-09-20  | 3522        | 2 | 2
2017-09-20  | 3522        | 2 | 2
```

Comment: Que valor es el que se repite?

Comment: Solo se te duplica una ves? O puede tener más de 2 duplicados?

Comment: Pueden haber mas duplicados pero solo quiero eliminar uno de estos dos que muestro en el código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tu problema es que el registro se repite "n" veces y **todos los campos son iguales**, lo que te sugiero es que generes una tabla provisional en la que se inserten los datos mediante un INSERT INTO, un SELECT y un DISTINCT.

```
INSERT INTO Ventas_dos  -- Tabla temporal
SELECT DISTINCT fecha_venta, monto_venta, F, M
FROM Ventas;
```

Luego deleteas el contenido de la tabla [Ventas]:

```
DELETE FROM Ventas;
```

Y luego insertas tus datos filtrados de la tabla [Ventas_dos]

```
INSERT INTO Ventas
SELECT* FROM Ventas_dos
```

Nota: Recuerda que la tabla [Ventas_dos] debe tener los mismos campos, en el mismo orden y del mismo tipo que la tabla [Ventas].

Saludos!

Comment: La respuesta que das es completamente valida, pero quiero saber si existe la forma de eliminarlos sin tener que crear una nueva tabla y, reitero, sin PK.

Comment: Para hacerlo sin alterar la base de datos declaramos una variable tipo tabla (Esto en SQL-Server):

`DECLARE @TablaTemporal as table
(
  --Declaracion de Columnas identicas al "Create Table" de la "TablaSinPK"
)
Insert into @TablaTemporal
Select Distinct * From TablaSinPK

Truncate TablaSinPK

Insert into TablaSinPK
Select * From @TablaTemporal`

Answer (score 2):

### **Para SQL Server:**

Para eliminar registros duplicados solo sería necesario realizar:

```
;WITH REGISTRO_DUPLICADO AS(
    SELECT
    INDICE = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fecha_venta, monto_venta, F, M ORDER BY fecha_venta),
    *
    FROM Ventas
)
DELETE FROM REGISTRO_DUPLICADO
WHERE INDICE > 1;
```

Eliminará los registros repetidos de tu tabla `Ventas` sin necesidad de crear tablas temporales.

---

Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Ventas (
    fecha_venta date,
    monto_venta decimal,
    F tinyint,
    M tinyint
)

INSERT INTO Ventas VALUES
('20170919', 3521, 2, 2),
('20170920', 3522, 2, 2),
('20170920', 3522, 2, 2),
('20170921', 3522, 2, 2),
('20170921', 3522, 2, 2),
('20170921', 3522, 2, 2)

SELECT * FROM Ventas

;WITH REGISTRO_DUPLICADO AS(
    SELECT
    INDICE = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fecha_venta, monto_venta, F, M ORDER BY fecha_venta),
    *
    FROM Ventas
)
DELETE FROM REGISTRO_DUPLICADO
WHERE INDICE > 1;

SELECT * FROM Ventas;
```

Obtendrás:

> ```
> +---------------------+-------------+---+---+
> |     fecha_venta     | monto_venta | F | M |
> +---------------------+-------------+---+---+
> | 19.09.2017 00:00:00 |        3521 | 2 | 2 |
> | 20.09.2017 00:00:00 |        3522 | 2 | 2 |
> | 20.09.2017 00:00:00 |        3522 | 2 | 2 |
> | 21.09.2017 00:00:00 |        3522 | 2 | 2 |
> | 21.09.2017 00:00:00 |        3522 | 2 | 2 |
> | 21.09.2017 00:00:00 |        3522 | 2 | 2 |
> +---------------------+-------------+---+---+
>
> +---------------------+-------------+---+---+
> |     fecha_venta     | monto_venta | F | M |
> +---------------------+-------------+---+---+
> | 19.09.2017 00:00:00 |        3521 | 2 | 2 |
> | 20.09.2017 00:00:00 |        3522 | 2 | 2 |
> | 21.09.2017 00:00:00 |        3522 | 2 | 2 |
> +---------------------+-------------+---+---+
> ```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/NXOMU95664)

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la sentencia With:

--1. Genera un partición por el campo fecha_venta

```
WITH tabla_auxiliar AS 
(
     *,id = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by fecha_venta order by fecha_venta) from Ventas
) 
select * into prueba from tabla_auxiliar where id = 1
delete from Ventas 
insert into Ventas (fecha_venta,monto_venta,F,M)
select fecha_venta,monto_venta,F,M
from prueba
drop table prueba
```

Comment: Hola Pablo Quintana, agradezco tu respuesta pero primero: no se viste que no utilizo ningún campo `id`, solo son los que ves en mi pregunta, así que no comprendo tu respuesta, segundo, ya lo he solucionado de otra forma, pero si se puede realizar me gustaría saber como de la forma en la que lo expones.

Comment: al ejecutar ROW_NUMBER() OVER crea un ídice "id" sin necesidad de que tu tabla lo tenga y lo inserta en la tabla prueba(tabla de transición) por medio de la sentencia WITH en funcion de la particion hecha por medio del campo <<fecha_venta>>(OJO debes confirmar que es el campo que no quieres que se repita), luego borra todo lo que posees en la tabla original , despues,  únicamente inserta  aquellas que tengan valor de 1 en la tabla original eliminando duplicidad en funcion del campo por el que particionaste. revisa prueba antes de borrarla.. exitos!!

Comment: Ejecuto el código y me aparece error de declaración WITH.

Comment: He mejorado el código para que puedas ejecutarlo en función de la estructura que mostraste en la pregunta, copialo nuevamente y coméntame tu resultado, exitos!!.

Comment: Agradezco nuevamente tu ayuda. pero arroja el mismo error... Análisis estático:encontraron 1 errores durante el análisis.  de declaración desconocida. (near "WITH" at position 0) SQL: Documentación